# what algorithm is good for the temperature system to send an email?

Tags: php, algorithm, email

The temperature system is plotted every 10 minutes (PHP and javascript). And the graph send an email if the temperature out of range. But I noticed the data graph I have , it run a cycle. So about every 12 hours, it send an email because it has a spike. Is anyone knows how to program a better algorithm to send an email ? [image]

Comment: Are you saying you only want it to send an email if it sustains an out of range temperature for a specific period of time maybe? Where is your code?

Comment: I programmed my code to send an email if the fourth data point is out of range continuously (so the first, second, third also out of range). But I received an email ( three or four times a day, which I do not like that). I am looking for better performance  like maybe using derivative or some other way

Comment: What would you like? Under which circumstances the email should be sent?

Comment: I am not sure. that is why I would like some opinion.

Comment: @Yang I don't think anyone can answer this besides you. We don't even know what type of device or system you're measuring the temperature of. You'll have to consult the manufacturer, coworkers, or other sources to see what temperature ranges can be sustained and what should be cause for concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you think it shouldn't go over a certain temperature, and it regularly does, perhaps you should fix the system to no longer go over that temperature?

That said, one standard solution to this is to maintain an exponential decaying average.  For this every 10 minutes you'd say `next_average = (1-p)*old_average + p*current_value`.  Set `p` to, say, `0.1` and what you'll get is roughly an average of the last 1.5 hours.  Make `p` smaller and you'll average over a longer time.  Make it larger and you will be effectively just averaging the last few data points.

This is exactly the algorithm used to compute the Unix load averages that you see with `uptime`.  (Those are basically 1, 5, and 15 minute moving averages.)

Comment: what is P ? and how to calculate the P ?

Comment: `p` is an arbitrary parameter that you are free to choose.  The smaller it is, the fewer alerts you'll get.  The larger it is, the faster you'll be alerted if there is a problem.  Experiment with it and decide what you like.